# CSS Invalid Property Value?

Tags: css

I don't understand what's wrong with this? I'm watching a tutorial and it seems to work fine on the video but both mozilla and chrome ignore this code and marks it as an invalid property value.

```
.btn {
    background-color: #4FB69F url("img/texture.png") no-repeat right top;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `background`?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

**change**

```
background-color:
```

**to**

```
background:
```

Because `background` is a shorthand property for

- background-color
- background-image
- background-position
- background-repeat
- background-attachment

Comment: Does this mean that 'background' can mean any of those things depending on context?

Comment: @AnsonSavage yes, it is called a shorthand property to shorten the code. Which allows you to specify all the background properties in one single property.

Answer (score 12):

If you are using inverted commas in your CSS, please remove them from  your CSS file.

For example, find difference between each CSS rule set for `.row`:

```
.row {
     margin-left:'-16px !important';
    margin-right:'0px !important';
}
```

```
.row {
    margin-left:-16px !important;
    margin-right:0px !important;
}
```

Comment: Removing inverted commas worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Another possible cause could be that you have a **"Hidden Character"** in the css property or value.

To fix that, copy the code directly from you IDE to some "Hidden Character" detector like this one https://www.soscisurvey.de/tools/view-chars.php ,delete the 'bad' characters and then save your code again without the bad characters.

Bonus: If you are using a JetBrains ide like WebStorm, this plugin can help you https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7448-zero-width-characters-locator

Answer (score 3):

I had similar problem .

I tried to apply background but there was a typo.

what i tried in CSS

```css
body{
  background:"#cebbc9"
  }
```

and I got this error

[image: the error I got]

simply remove the double quotes from the value. as the hex value in css is not in double quotes.

```css
body{
  background:#cebbc9
  }
```

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 2):

Not directly a solution but a typo in CSS property value caused similar issue for me:

```
.PokeCard {
border: 2px solic mediumseagreen;
}
```

The problem was a typo *solic* instead of *solid*.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
background-color: #4FB69F; 
background-image: url('images/texture.png'); 
background-repeat: no-repeat; 
background-position: right top;
```

Within the image url requires **'** not **"**
Background position is separate from no repeat
and **;** between each element control

Answer (score 0):

*Instead of writing:*

```
.btn {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  background-image: url("img_tree.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right top;
}
```

*You can use the shorthand property background:*

```
.btn {
  background: #ffffff url("img_tree.png") no-repeat right top;
}
```

It does not matter if one of the property values is missing, as long as the other ones are in this order.
[know more](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background_shorthand.asp)